# shell script to check if website is up and fill excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, shell, unix

I want to check if a particular set of websites(around 20) is up or not. This should be done daily at a particular user defined time and the status of the website should be filled in an Excel Sheet and the Excel sheet should be mailed to the user defined email address. 
Is this possible? If yes, what should be the shell script?

Comment: Its always good to know about what you want.

Comment: It would be fairly simple to do in a shell script, Perl, Python... any scripting language.The simplest option would be to email a CSV file rather than an Excel specific format document.